# ConstraintLayout: How to add several views programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to add 2 buttons to a ConstraintLayout. My current code is as following:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(layout);

    //Button 1: 
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Hello");
    layout.addView(button);

    set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, layout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    set.constrainWidth(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    set.constrainHeight(button.getId(), 200);
    set.applyTo(layout);


    //Button 2:     
    Button newButton = new Button(this);
    newButton.setText("Yeeey");
    layout.addView(newButton);

    set.connect(newButton.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    set.connect(newButton.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, button.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
    set.connect(newButton.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, button.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
    set.constrainHeight(newButton.getId(), 200);
    set.applyTo(layout);

}
```

But I only get 1 visible button (the other is probably hidden behind this one), and it's in the top left corner of the screen. There's supposed to be 2 buttons, at the bottom of the screen, linked to each other.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Desired outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is the working code of what you want to achieve

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(layout);

        //Button 1:
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Hello");
        button.setId(100);           // <-- Important
        layout.addView(button);
        set.connect(button.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(button.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(button.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);


        //Button 2:
        Button newButton = new Button(this);
        newButton.setText("Yeeey");
        layout.addView(newButton);
        set.connect(newButton.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, button.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        set.connect(newButton.getId(),ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
        set.connect(newButton.getId(),ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0);
        set.constrainHeight(newButton.getId(), 200);
        set.applyTo(layout);


    }
```

**Important:**
If `id` is not set explicitly, all the elements will get the same id(-1).

Comment: Great. This is working code. I can see you've added "button.setID(100);" and changed "layout.getId()" to "ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID". Could you explain to me why this made it work?

Comment: We want to set our button to the bottom of parent layout so using "ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID" is more appropriate and while setting newButton to the top of button I've used the code before adding button.setId() and it wasn't giving me the perfect output so I've to set the id using java code.

Comment: I see. Thank you. For others reading these comments: I printed the content of .getId() for each button. If the .setId() is not used then it just defaults the ID to -1. Which means all your buttons have an ID of -1. In that case, your set.connect()'s will not be able to distinguish from one button to another.

Comment: @Einar this explanation really helped me. The setId was key, to fixing my issues.

Comment: Einar's comment really helps, thus added to answer.

Comment: you should use `View.generateViewId()` instead of using an literal int as argument.

Comment: Adding id something that is not going to be inflated, just fixed with setId(), many thanks!