# When creating an ImageButton programmatically it is not added to view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to add an ImageButton to a specific constraint layout programmatically. One that is also constrained to specific guidelines. So far I have implemented the below method and it gives no errors, however, other than the debugText, nothing appears to happen.

```
public void addButtonImage () {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage); // - Moved out of method
    ConstraintLayout conL = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
    ImageButton previewImg = new ImageButton(this);
    Guideline leftGl = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.leftGideLine);
    Guideline rightGL = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.rightGuideLine);
    ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Header);

    previewImg.setImageBitmap(displayImage); // displayImage variable assigned out of method
    previewImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
    conL.addView(previewImg);

    ConstraintSet conS = new ConstraintSet();
    conS.clone(conL);

    conS.constrainHeight(pp.getId(), 90);
    conS.constrainWidth(pp.getId(), 0);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, header.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, leftGl.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, rightGL.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    conS.applyTo(conL);
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add image button but you got to set constraints to fit your needs.

instead of using : `previewImg.setImageBitmap(displayImage);`

use this : `previewImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`

```
public void addButtonImage () {
    ConstraintLayout conL = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.newLayout);
    ImageButton previewImg = new ImageButton(this);
    Guideline leftGl = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.leftGideLine);
    Guideline rightGL = (Guideline)findViewById(R.id.rightGuideLine);
    ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Header);

    previewImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); // displayImage variable assigned out of method
    previewImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
    conL.addView(previewImg);

    ConstraintSet conS = new ConstraintSet();
    conS.clone(conL);

    conS.constrainHeight(pp.getId(), 90);
    conS.constrainWidth(pp.getId(), 0);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, header.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, leftGl.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
    conS.connect(previewImg.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, rightGL.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
    conS.applyTo(conL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information however, the image or background colour still isn't appearing.

Comment: CORRECTION!  something is now appearing! its not in the right place and had to combine it with alexscmar's answer below, but enough for me to work with. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull about your setContentView method. Other than that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41671717) answer can get you to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the linked question doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks OK, but your never define a resource id for the added `ImageView`. As a result, your statement `previewImg.getId()` will return "NO_ID"

Set an id for the new `ImageView` as follows:

```
    previewImg.setId(View.generateViewId()); // API 17+
```

Answer (score 0):

You **need to set LayoutParams** of your ImageButton:

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

previewImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

also you may need to set margins and padding.

Comment: Thanks for the help something is now appearing! its not in the right place and had to combine it with vikas kumar's answer above, but enough for me to work with. Many thanks!