# How do I move a TextView using ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with the work I was assigned. I was asked to use ConstraintLayout to move a TextView. I have the code for the TextView in a **content_main.xml** file, and the skeleton code for moving the TextView in the **MainActivity.java** file. I need to understand how to (pardon my lack of jargon) 'connect' the .xml and the .java file. Moving the TextView using a method in my .java file, even though any code changes to ConstraintLayout need to be done in the .xml file is something I don't understand right now. I've posted the relevant code below for further insight.

**content_main** Code:

```
     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nav Drawer Demo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

**MainActivity.java** Code:

```
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //ConstraintSet cs = new ConstraintSet();
    //cs.clone(constraintLayout); //should have in the brackets the constraint layout

    if (id == R.id.up) {
        textView.
        // Handle the up action
    } else if (id == R.id.down) {
        // Handle the down action
    } else if (id == R.id.left) {
        // Handle the left action
    } else if (id == R.id.right) {
        // Handle the right action

    }
```

Any help whatsoever would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666566/constraintlayout-how-to-add-several-views-programmatically

Comment: I think this is what you expected. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909741/android-positioning-views-programatically